# Getting the username from the session in onAuthenticationFailure()

Tags: php, symfony

In short: In a [Custom Authentication System with Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/guard_authentication.html), how can I access the username that is currently in the session, not the one in the current login attempt?

Longer version:
I use an url containing a token to authenticate the user. If the token gets invalidated while the user is logged in, and then the user opens the same url again, the situation is: The current login attempt fails (i.e. `onAuthenticationFailure()` kicks in), since the token isn't valid anymore. However, the user is still logged in, since the data in the session was never changed. In Twig, `{{ app.user }}` gives me what I'm looking for (i.e. the username from the session). How can I access it from within `onAuthenticationFailure()`?

Answer (score 0):

Inject [`\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface`](https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorageInterface.html) into your Authenticator Class (`TokenAuthenticator.php`
) and call `->getToken()->getUser()` on it.

If the user was not logged in before, `->getToken()` is `null`.